# Tensor product of tensors of mixed type

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products

In wikipedia page of tensor product, there is a tensor product of mixed type tensors:
[image]

I wonder exactly how the map works (it takes in ... and spits out ...). Can someone help me to find an explicit form of this map? I met this problem when looking at second covariant derivative of tensor fields. Thanks.

Comment: It is a simple re-ordering such that all "normal" tensors are on the left and all "dual" tensors are on the right. It is simply $a\otimes b\longmapsto b\otimes a$ as often as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I guess I'm just being stupid. If I am correct, the map should be like this:

$$
\begin{align*}
\otimes: T^{(k,l)}(V)\times T^{(k',l')}(V)&\to T^{(k+k',l+l')}(V)\\
(A,B)&\mapsto A\otimes B
\end{align*}
$$
where
$$
A\otimes B(\omega^1,\cdots,\omega^k,\omega^{k+1},\cdots,\omega^{k+k'},v_1,\cdots,v_k,v_{l+1},\cdots,v_{l+l'}):=A(\omega^1,\cdots,\omega^k,v_1,\cdots,v_l)B(\omega^{k+1},\cdots,\omega^{k+k'},v_{l+1},\cdots,v_{l+l'})
$$

We may use the identification of $T^{(k,l)}(V)=V^{\otimes k}\otimes (V^*)^{\otimes l}\cong \mathcal{L}((V^*)^{\times k},V^{\times l};\mathbb R)$ (same for $T^{(k',l')}(V)$) and the usual tensor product of multilinear maps to get the above definition.

Comment: This is correct. You feed what you can to the first tensor until it gets full, then move on to the next.